# PostgreSQL function is slow based on different input

Tags: postgresql, function

Any tips on why this function is slow *sometimes*?

```
create function getGeometry(numeric(38,8)) returns st_geometry
AS $$
select shape
from shape_table
where someid = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

select getGeometry(367214918);
```

There is an index on `someid` field.
Function sometimes returns in 40ms sometimes in 1500ms based on the number I pass in. If I query without function it always returns result under 50ms.

```
select shape
from shape_table
where someid = 367214918;
```

Would appreciate any ideas how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the SELECT statement? (both situations, slow and fast query)

Comment: For select statement: "Index Scan using xmadpmatrikkel on gis.matrikkel_adressepunkt  (cost=0.00..9.08 rows=7 width=495)"
"  Output: shape"
"  Index Cond: (matrikkel_adressepunkt.matrikkelenhetid = 367214918)"

Comment: For function: "Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0)"
"  Output: getteigforadresse(367214918::numeric)"

Comment: I am not sure what is happening because I have similar function for other table and everything seems to be identical. Obviously something is not, but I cannot troubleshoot.

Comment: Please provide: the data types of `someid ` and `shape` in the underlying table, the exact index definition, the cardinality of the table (how many rows?) and your version of Postgres.

Comment: is someid a unique column? Have you vacuumed recently?

Comment: someid: integer
shape: st_point
CREATE INDEX shapeindex
  ON shape_table
  USING gist
  (shape);


CREATE INDEX someidindex
  ON shape_table
  USING btree
  (someid)
  WITH (FILLFACTOR=75);
  
2.437.528 rows.